# Возможно ли извлечь векто битов из класса bitset?

Tags: c++

bitset предоставляет возможность извлечь массив чаров, заполненные единицами и нулями и инт, но можно ли извлечь сам массив битов. Т.е например битсет из 16 значений, это, по сути, массив чаров из 2 элементов, возможно ли извлечь этот массив чаров? Так же, можно ли проинициализировать битсет таким массивом? В каких случая выгодно использовать этот класс?

Comment: Похоже нельзя, и то и другое.

Comment: Ну, в принципе, до 64 бит можно трактовать `unsigned long long` как массив из 8 `char`ов...